# Gets(string#) function skipping first gets request

Tags: c, string, gets

I'm working on a project for my own personal leisure and learning. Part of it looks like this:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 wgame()
 {
 char string3[12], string2[12], string1[12], string4[12], string5[12];
 memset (string1, 0, 11);
 memset (string2, 0, 11);
 memset (string3, 0, 11);
 memset (string4, 0, 11);
 memset (string5, 0, 11);
 printf("reference C correct\n");
 printf("Okay, so you want a game. Here's one for you\n\n\n");
 printf("This is a word game.\n\n   A noun is a person place or thing.\n   A verb is 
 something that you can get up and do.\n   A subject is what the conversation is about.\n");
 printf("Go ahead, type a subject:\n");
 gets(string3);
 printf("That's a good one. Now, type a verb:\n");
 gets(string2);
 printf("How about another:\n");
 gets(string4);
 printf("Really? Okay. Now, type in a noun:\n");
 gets(string1);
 printf("Cool. How about typing another noun:\n");
 gets(string5);
 printf("Allright, here's how your words fit into this game:\n\n\n\n\n");
 printf("When the %s was %s the %s %s all the other %s", string1, 
 string2, string3, string4, string5);
 return 4;

 }
```

My problem is that the output is skipping over the first "gets(string#)" and proceeding to the 
next "printf()". Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: `wgame()` should be `int wgame(void)`.  *Never* use `gets()`; it cannot be used safely, and is being removed from the language.  Use meaningful variable names.  Avoid "magic numbers" (`11`, `12`).  Indent your code.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that before `wgame` you are doing some `scanf` that leaves a `\n` in the stdio buffer.

Here are a few things you should do:

- Don't mix `scanf` and `gets`
- Don't use `gets`. Use `fgets`
- **Don't listen to people suggesting `fflush(stdin)`. It's wrong**.

With great care and moderation, you could use:

```
/* Right before `wgame` begins. */
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    ;
```

However, be aware it should be used sparingly, discarding user input is dangerous.

Read this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html) on the subject, and an [explanation](http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html) about flushing stdin.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define size 5

void main()
  {
   char *str,*name[size];
   int i,n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("%d",n);
   fflush(stdin); // using fflush here gets() isn't skipping else i have to use scanf()
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
       str = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
       printf("enter  a name :\n");
       //scanf("%s",str);
       gets(str);
       name[i]=str;
     }
   printf("the entered names  :\n");
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   puts(name[i]);
  }
```

Comment: You might want to explain what you are doing here, for people facing similar problems in the future :)